# Regarding MDI form in WPF

Tags: wpf

how to make a MDI form in WPF. looking for answer. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such Property for a window to make it MDI

instead you can use the library [WPF Multiple Document Interface (MDI)](http://wpfmdi.codeplex.com/)